# Why am I getting an error while running this code?

Tags: c#, list, exception, console-application, stack-overflow

When I was running a console application, I got this stack overflow error.
As this error seems to be in the Assignlogic part of my code, I have wrote down that part of code and the error which is shown. My question is how to handle this exception, without changing the functionality of code?

```
//Assign
    public class Assignlogic 
    {
        private List<Assign> Assigns { get; set; } = new List<Assign>();//Here exception unhandled was thrown
//System.StackOverflowException: 'Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.'

        readonly Assignlogic logicC = new Assignlogic();

        
            

        public void AddEmployeetoProject(Assign assign, Employeelogic logicA, Projectlogic logicB)
        {
            List<Employee> Employes = logicA.Employees;
            List<Project> Projcts = logicB.Projects;
            List<Assign> Assignss = logicC.Assigns;
            var id = assign.EmpId;
            var pid = assign.PID;
            var emp = Employes.Find(a => a.EmpId == id);
            var prjct = Projcts.Find(c => c.PID == pid);
            if (emp != null || prjct != null)
            {
                Assignss.Add(assign);
            }
        }

        //view all assigned projects
        public List<Assign> GetAllAssignedProjects()
        {
            return Assigns;
        }

        //remove an employee from a project
        public void RemoveEmployee(string id)
        {
            var emp = Assigns.Find(a => a.EmpId == id);
            if (emp != null)
            {
                Assigns.Remove(emp);
            }
            
        }

        public bool SearchProjectbyMappedId(string id)
        {
            var employee = Assigns.Find(c => c.EmpId == id);
            if (employee != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: The problem is actually `readonly Assignlogic logicC = new Assignlogic()` -- you've stipulated that in order to construct a new `Assignlogic`, first an `Assignlogic` should be constructed... It's unclear what you were going for here, perhaps a `static`?

Comment: Thanks guys, the instance was creating recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when you create an instance of `Assignlogic`?  This:

```
readonly Assignlogic logicC = new Assignlogic();
```

So creating an instance of `Assignlogic` creates an instance of `Assignlogic`, which creates an isntance of `Assignlogic`, which creates an instance of `Assignlogic`, etc., etc.

I don't know what your *intent* is here, but this is clearly not the way to do it.  Objects shouldn't recursively create themselves ad infinitum.

Comment: Also, this is a good opportunity to learn that stack trace line numbers are frequently off-by-one for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

you have this member in your class AssignLogic

```
    readonly Assignlogic logicC = new Assignlogic();
```

So when you create an AssignLogic, it has to go and create an AssignLogic to put there. Creating that AssignLogic requires another AssignLogic,.......